# List Comprehension in haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am new to Haskell and learning about lists. I have the following list `[1, 2, 3]` and another list `[4, 5, 6]`. I am trying to find a way to get the following output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
```

That is, for each element in the second list, I want to create a new list which is the first list with that element appended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [4, 5, 6]`, you can do something like this:

```
map (\x -> a ++ [x]) b
```

For each element of `b`, `map` will apply the function `\x -> a ++ [x]`.
This function concatenates two lists, `a` and `[x]`.

You can also write it as a list comprehension:

```
[a ++ [x] | x <- b]
```